# Fixed point, mapping in $\ell^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Could you tell me how to prove that the following mappinmg has no fixed point?

Let $B=B(0,1)=$ closed unit ball in $\ell^2$, $\  x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots) \in \ell^2$

$$\varphi : B \ni (x_1, x_2, \ldots) \rightarrow (\sqrt{1-\|x\|}, x_1, x_2, \ldots) \in B$$

By calculating $\|\varphi (x)\|$ we can see that the mapping is well defined (we indeed land in $B$) and it's bounded : $\| \varphi \| \le 1$.

However, I don't know what to do about the fixed point:

$$
\begin{align}
\varphi (x) = x & \iff (x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (\sqrt{1-\|x\|}, x_1, x_2, \ldots) \\
& \iff x_1 = \sqrt{1-\|x\|}, x_2 = x_1, x_3 = x_2, \ldots
\end{align}
$$

So $x_1 = x_2= \cdots = \sqrt{1-\|x\|}$

Now, why does that lead to contradiction?

Comment: What conditions are imposed on $p$?

Comment: Stupid me, p=2, I'll correct it right away!

Comment: Hint: A constant sequence can't be in $\ell^2$ unless it is the constant zero sequence.

Comment: What's the $\ell^2$ norm of the fixed point?

Comment: The norm of the fixed point is $\sqrt{\sum(1-||x||)}$. And this series is divergent because its terms do not tend to zero. Thank you!